# Can not cast type [String: Any] to User?

Tags: swift, firebase

I am trying to assign fetched user to the created currentUser variable

```
@Published var userSession: Firebase.User?
@Published var currentUser: User?

func fetchUser() {
    guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _  in
        guard let user = snapshot?.data() else { return }
        self.currentUser = user
    }
}
```

and have an error such as Cannot assign value of type '[String : Any]' to type 'User'

[image]

Comment: Please post the structure of your firebase collection without which no one will be able to tell what exactly the issue is

Comment: I've posted my structure as image

Comment: Why are you doing this? The built in User is part of Firebase Authentication and automatically populates when a user authenticates - and there's a limited set of data that composes a User - See [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users). If you want to load other data, then create your own UserClass object and populate it with data you've retrieved from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to put a data of array type `[String: any]` to a variable of type `User`

So you can start with something like this since there is a lot of unclear mechanism in the code, this is what I could come up with

```
guard let array = snapshot?.data() else return // Type is [String: Any]
for item in array {
  var email = item["email"]
  var username = item["username"] // and so on
  var user = // Your constructor that will do all the initialization of User with different values
 // and in the end
  self.currentUser = user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a User `NSObject` like this:

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    
    @objc var email: String?
    @objc var fullname: String?
    @objc var username: String?
    @objc var profileImgUrl: String?
    @objc var userId: String?
    
    init(dict: [String: AnyObject], uid: String) {
        
        self.email = dict["email"] as? Strings
        self.fullname = dict["fullname"] as? String
        self.username = dict["username"] as? String
        self.profileImgUrl = dict["profileImgUrl"] as? String
        
        self.userId = uid
    }
}
```

And then fetch user like this:

```
var currentUser: User?

func fetchUser() {
    guard let uid = userSession?.uid else { return }
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, _  in
        if let dict = snapshot?.data() as [String: AnyObject]?, let userId = snapshot.documentID {
           let user = User(dict: dict, uid: userId)
           self.currentUser = user
        } 
    }
}
```

Remember that `User` object values are optional, so you need to unwrap them safely before using them. Example:

```
if let fullname = currentUser?.fullname {
    print(fullname)
}
```